# Is ASP.Net Dynamic Data open source?

Tags: open-source, asp.net-dynamic-data

According to this article http://www.infoq.com/articles/role-open-source-asp.net Dynamic Data is open source. However I could not find System.Web.DynamicData on http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4284ca5270b9 and google search failed me as well.

Is Asp.Net Dynamic Data open source? If yes, can anyone provide the link to the repository please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not open source.  I think the reference in the article cited refers to open source **projects** built with DynamicData.dll, but not the dll itself.